# Web Api + AngularJs on azure in one solution

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have deployed Web Api + angular js application to azure web apps in one visual studio solution.The starting page (index page) is in index.cshtml format.

I cannot for some reason navigate to my angular page. i.e if i go to
webname.azurewebsites.net/#/signin  i get the following message angular doesn't seem to activate.

```
This web app has been successfully created

There's nothing here yet, but Microsoft Azure makes it simple to publish content with GIT, FTP or your favorite development tool such as Visual Studio, Visual Studio Online or WebMatrix

Tell me more
```

However, I can access the Web api part just fine. I call web api using: webname.azurewebsites.net/api/getitems <-- this works fine.

i presume there might be something to do with index.csthml file that I am using (it works fine in local iis).

Is there anything specific i need to do on azure to use index.shtml file with angular?

If i use index.html file it works fine. The only reason why i am using the index.cshtml is that i can utilize the asp.net bundling feature. I am aware that i can use grunt to do the bundling minification but at this stage i don't the time to invest in implementing grunt.

Comment: May be this will help you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313790/how-to-set-default-page-in-angular

Comment: post your code for index.csthml